# How do you make a PivotItemHeader in UWP Visibility Follow the PivotItem's Visibility?

Tags: c#, uwp, pivot, controls, pivotitem

I have a Pivot with several static PivotItems and several dynamically generated ones in code behind. I want to be able to hide the PivotHeaderItems by changing the PivotItem's Visibility property.

Here is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
    <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemChromeLowColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid" CornerRadius="4" Margin="4" Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full"/>
                            <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1.33" />
                                <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1.33" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                             Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                             Duration="0" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAccentColorLight3}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemControlHighlightAccent3RevealBackgroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAccentColorLight3}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAccentColorLight3}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SystemAccentColorLight3}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter
                x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                Padding="4 8 4 4"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Grid.Row="0">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="0 0 4 4" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" Height="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is my Pivot XAML code:

```
<Pivot Name="SettingsPivot">

    <PivotItem Name="SubscriptionsandUpdatesPivot" Header="Subscription and Version" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <StackPanel Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="Premium Subscription:" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="SubscriptionStatus" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="8" Text="Loading..." Custom:DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="BuyMonthlySubscriptionButton" Margin="8" Content="Purchase Monthly Subscription" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Custom:DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="BuyMonthlySubscriptionButton_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" Text=" * unlocks Dashboards, Patients Finder, Sending Emails and Scheduler." />
            <TextBlock Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text=" * in this version, all features are unlocked for testing purposes." />
            <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="Current Version: " />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="VersionStatus" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="8" Text="Please Wait ..." />
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="VersionInfoPage" Content="See Version Features" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="UpdateButton" Margin="8" Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="false"  Click="UpdateButton_Click"/>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <Custom:DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ScrollViewer BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                        
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Custom:DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>

</Pivot>
```

I have tried setting **Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}"** in the main Grid that makes the PivotItemHeader but it does not follow the PivotItem's.Visibility.

This is what the design looks like now[image]

Comment: The code `Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}"` provided by you binds the value of `Visibility` of item header to the `Visibility` value in Setter(such as             `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>`) instead of the value of `Visibility` property of pivot item. 
Could you please tell me what the purpose of setting the `Visibility` of a `PivotHeaderItem` of Pivot control?

Comment: I have an interface where the Pivot is being used as a Wizard of some sorts where the SelectedIndex is advanced to show the next PivotItem. I want to prevent the user from manually being able to selected the PivotItem using the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change visibility of a `PivotItem` this way, as the "item" still remains in the item collection of the control. Instead, you need to remove it from the control itself (and later re-add it as needed):

```
// Remove item
SettingsPivot.Items.Remove(SubscriptionsandUpdatesPivot);

// Re-add item
SettingsPivot.Items.Add(SubscriptionsandUpdatesPivot);
```

Comment: Removing it isn't really an option as all the content is also removed.

Comment: As long as the item has `x:Name` assigned, it is only removed from the visual tree, but the item itself remains in memory. When you re-add it later, all the content should be intact.

Comment: Thanks! Would only x:Name work or Name also would keep it in the memory and can be readded through the visual tree?

Comment: There is only slight difference between `x:Name` and `Name`, in this case the difference does not matter, so you can use either :-) . In short, `x:Name` can be used with any XAML element, while `Name` is only usable with `FrameworkElement` based elements.

Comment: If the answer resolved the issue, please consider accepting it, so that the question is resolved :-)

Comment: I am still looking for an elegant way to just hide either the whole header component of pivot items or be able to hide individual header times rather than deleting them and re-adding them back because in my wizard style navigation, removing will mean the index will also change. E.g. I have register > connect > user name > password. I don't want users to be able to jump to password before having gone through all the other steps hence the need to just hide the header component and allow me to programatically advance the selectedindex.

Comment: The index will change, but you could just query for the right position by using `IndexOf` on the tab that precedes this one, or alternatively, you could store the index when removing the item and then `Insert` at that same position again

Comment: Any way of just hiding the whole header panel?

Comment: You could hide the header panel completely by editing the `Pivot` template and making the header `Collapsed`. In such case though, wouldn't a `FlipView` be more suitable?

Comment: I gave FlipView a try - you're right works better but still requires changing the default style to remove buttons and disallow scrolling through the items!

Comment: Unfortauntely, Keyboard Accelerators (Enter) does not work in FlipViewItem for whatever reason. Is there any work around to this? I have the keyboard accelerator declared under a button.